# How to do effective search in JedisCluster in a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis

How to do effective search of json in JedisCluster in a spring boot application
If we have jedis cluster and i want to search on the basis of a key how can we do that effectively?
Suppose I have an User object and i want to filter it based on user address how can i do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.